# Output taxonomy terms - show none if none selected

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I've got a working shortcode that outputs the terms of a taxonomy as image thumbnails.

It works great, BUT when none of the taxonomy terms are selected, it outputs ALL terms.

My current code is as follows:

```
add_shortcode( 'book-accreditation', 'book_accreditation_output' );
function book_accreditation_output($atts){

    ob_start();
    echo '<div id="book-terms-wrap"><ul class="book-terms">';

    global $post;
    $taxonomy = 'book_accreditation';
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids'));

    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'include'  => $post_terms
      )
  );

  foreach($terms as $term){
    $thumbnail = get_field('bkk_taxonomy_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
    $thumbnail = $thumbnail['url'];
    $name = $term->name;
    $url = get_term_link($term, $taxonomy);
    echo '<li><img src="' . $thumbnail . '" class="accreditation-image"></li>';
  }
    echo '</ul></div>';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
```

I'm trying to fix this with `if (!empty())` variable targeting the `$terms`, but i'm probably not putting the code correctly.

So if NO terms are selected, then nothing should output.

I'm adding the code as follows:

```
add_shortcode( 'book-accreditation', 'book_accreditation_output' );
function book_accreditation_output($atts){

  global $post;
  $taxonomy = 'book_accreditation';
  $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids'));

  $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'include'  => $post_terms
  )
  );

  if (!empty($terms)) {
    ob_start();
    echo '<div id="book-terms-wrap"><ul class="book-terms">';

    foreach($terms as $term){
    $thumbnail = get_field('bkk_taxonomy_image', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
    $thumbnail = $thumbnail['url'];
    $name = $term->name;
    $url = get_term_link($term, $taxonomy);
    echo '<li><img src="' . $thumbnail . '" class="accreditation-image"></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul></div>';
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
  }
}
```

But this won't work unfortunately, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$terms` is undefined at the point you are testing it

Comment: @Nick thanks, I have edited the code in my question, see above. I have now defined the $terms before the !empty variable, but still can't seem to make it working. What should the code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but are checking in the wrong spot.

[wp_get_object_terms returns an empty array if the Post has no such terms.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/)

get_terms, [namely the WP_Term_query array of arguments passed in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/), accepts the `includes` parameter as you have it, but if you don't provide `includes` the default `includes` is an empty array. That is, passing in an empty array is identical to not passing the parameter at all - meaning, it ignores the `includes` limitation entirely and returns all results matching any other limits (in your case, it simply returns all of them).

So in brief, you know that you have no terms as soon as your $post_terms line is called. You can use the following:

```
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids'));

// No terms found, skip the rest of the function
if ( empty($post_terms) )
  return false

$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'include'  => $post_terms
)
```

As an aside, I'm reasonably certain you can also skip the `get_terms` call entirely by changing the `wp_get_object_terms` line as follows:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false) );
```